# How volume of plasma in B That can affect A increases as $r^3$ if we consider effect of two slightly charged region separated by $r$ distance?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, charge, plasma-physics, coulombs-law

In plasma physics by Chen, in the topic collective behaviour, it is written: Let us consider the effect on each other of two slightly charged regions A and B separated by a distance $r$ coulomb force between A and B diminishes as $1/r^2$. However for a given solid angle the volume of plasma in B that can affect A increases as $r^3$.

My question is how it increases as $r^3$?

Comment: In a 3D world the volume goes as length cubed, does it not?

Comment: Ya ya ryt ryt!  I got it! @honeste_vivere